# VBA EXCEL REPLACE in database or dont copy if already there

Tags: vba, excel, integrity

[First View (FIRST SHEET FOR UPLOADING)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5pkO.png)

[Second View (DATABASE WHERE DATA IS PARSED AND MANUAL EDITION IS BLOCKED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkFPJ.png)

[SUB I MADE FOR DATA VALIDATION AND PARSING INFO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxHTb.png)

Hi fellow devs,
      This is my first time using VBA. Im stucked atm because i need to add some functionality i cant figure out. I need to modify my sub so if by any chance there is a duplicate row on the "UPLOAD" slide it wont paste again in my "BASE" and if there is the same line but QTY modified it should update to new QTY. Could you please help me figure out how to change my sub?

Tks and regards.

EDIT:

This is the SUB:

```
Sub Button_Click()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UPLOAD").Range("C4", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
For Each c In Worksheets("UPLOAD").Range("C4", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
   If (Len(c) <> 12) And (c <> "") Then
      c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      MsgBox ("Faltan 12ncs!! Porfavor agreguelos o corrija los que estén mal.")
      Exit Sub
   End If
   Next c

a = Worksheets("UPLOAD").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To a



Worksheets("UPLOAD").Rows(i).Copy

Worksheets("BASE").Activate

b = Worksheets("BASE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("BASE").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Worksheets("UPLOAD").Activate

Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets("UPLOAD").Cells(1, 1).Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you are making a list to check against in a single column (a unique ID?), if not you have to check every item in the row for uniqueness.  I see you are not familiar with arrays, so I am assuming no dictionary/key set up.  If you have a unique item in the row to verify against a unique list this should be straight forward.  So far it looks like you want a string that is not empty and exactly 12 characters?  Give us a some very descriptive detail here on the comparison.

Answer (score -1):

### Before Loop

1. Create an array
2. Loop through your items

### Inside the loop

1. Check if id is inside the array, skip item
2. Add id to the array
3. Upload item

Comment: Thanks for the approach, but im not familiar with vba data structures analysis, id prefer some written e.g. if udm.